# Android, обновления базы данных

Tags: android, база-данных, mobile-development, синхронизация, хранение-данных

Добрый день.

Никак не могу понять, как можно подписаться на обновления базы данных (SQLiteDatabase) в андроиде?

На данный момент есть несколько проблем:

- Изменение из другого процесса (если её изменили, а мы используем обычный паттерн observer, то в нашем процессе обновления не произойдёт.
- Изменение из другого экземпляра класса. Проблема как в прошлом пункте.

Я пытался использовать FileObserver (подписывался на события MODIFY файла базы данных), но у него есть проблемы:

- Фактически он уведомляет о КАЖДОМ изменении бд. То есть или на него нужно вешать какой-то debounce, или уже справляться в подписчиках.
- Одно изменение (особенно insert) может порождать более одного события MODIFY.
- Событие происходит до того, как бд в объекте синхронизируется. То есть если мы уведомили, в экземплярах бд данные могли не обновиться (состояние гонки).

Я пытался использовать связку `FileObserver -> обновление бд объектов -> рассылка подписчикам`, но по какой-то причине в бд данные всё ещё оказывались не актуальны.

Использование ContentProvider прошу не предлагать, поскольку подразумевается, что изменения могут быть получены не только в UI.

Таким образом, вопрос:
Можно ли как-то следить за обновлениями базы данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инкарнация SQLite в Android не поддерживает механизм слушателя на изменения БД. Тем не менее вижу 3 способа:

1) **Путь героя:** повесить через Android NDK [хук слушателя модификаций](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/preupdate_count.html)

2) **Красиво сделать через ORM:** взять какой-нибудь ORM, например мой любимый [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) или [GreenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/) и повесить слушателя модификаций уже не на модификацию БД, а на модификации объектов поверх SQLite

3) **Cамый правильный:**, но почему-то нелюбимый вами - через `ContentProvider`. Пишете весь доступ к SQLite через `ContentProvider` и вешаете `ContentObserver`:

```
 //создаем слушателя
 MyObserver myObserver = new MyObserver(new Handler());
 //вешаем слушателя на URI провайдера
 getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(URI,true,myObserver);
```

Если вы полагаете, что `ContentObserver` будет слушать только модификации сделанные через UI - спешу вас разочаровать - вы не правы

Comment: Если я верно понял, любое изменение извне, вызванное не контент провайдером, отзывается отсутствием события, а значит контент провайдер не решает задачу

Comment: Да, именно так. Сделайте чтобы все изменения были только через `ContentProvider` и будет вам счастье - что-то мешает? Есть какие то злобные силы, которые лезут к БД мимо провайдера?

Comment: Ага, разработчики называется:)

Comment: А если серьезно, это выход, но только в одном случае - если подписаться на настоящие изменения бд не выйдет.

Comment: Насчет последнего про модификации из UI - я понимаю, что контент обсервер получает обновления из любого места, НО только когда об этом уведомляется. То есть прослушиваются не обновления базы данных, а события контент провайдера, что несколько не соответствует ожидаемому решению.

Comment: Ну нет такого листенера, можно только написать самому через JNI/NDK - слушая [SQLite update hook](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html). Мне кажется проще будет дисциплинировать разработчиков, дав им в руки стандартный набор CRUD операций через `ContentProvider`

Comment: Понял вас, благодарю